# Can't create collision mesh for a child gameobject

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am creating fbx-processing script to change certain mesh parameters, create prefab and add collision mesh automatically. Now I am stuck trying to add collision mesh component to certain child of my gameobject.
But have no luck so far. I have a error message 
"Can't add component 'MeshCollider' to UCX_SM_bench_1_LOD0 because the game object is a generated prefab and can only be modified through an AssetPostprocessor."
I am using Unity 2017.1.

I am a 3D artist and it is my first attempt in scripting.

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEditor;

public class ModelAssetPostprocessor : AssetPostprocessor
{
public void OnPreprocessModel()
{
    ModelImporter modelImporter = assetImporter as ModelImporter;
    modelImporter.importAnimation = false;
    modelImporter.importBlendShapes = false;
    modelImporter.importCameras = false;
    modelImporter.importVisibility = false;
    modelImporter.importLights = false;
    modelImporter.importTangents = ModelImporterTangents.Import;
}
private const string PREFAB_DESTINATION_DIRECTORY = "Assets/Prefabs/";//setting up constant for prefabs destination directory

private static void OnPostprocessAllAssets(
    string[] importedAssets,
    string[] deletedAssets,
    string[] movedAssets,
    string[] movedFromAssetPaths)           
{
    foreach (string path in importedAssets) 
    {
        if (!path.EndsWith(".fbx", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)) //skipping all the files, which are not .fbx
            continue;

        GameObject modelAsset = AssetDatabase.LoadAssetAtPath<GameObject>(path);    //As far as I understand here we declare local variable "modelAsset"
                                                                                    //It will become GameObject, which took from AssetDatabase using path we saved before. So
                                                                                    //Now we have a GameObject. 
        CreatePrefabFromModel(path, modelAsset);
        //And now we declare a function to create prefab from our game object
    }
}

private static void CreatePrefabFromModel(string path, GameObject modelAsset)
{
    EnsureDirectoryExists(PREFAB_DESTINATION_DIRECTORY);

    string modelFileName = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(path);
    string destinationPath = PREFAB_DESTINATION_DIRECTORY + modelFileName + ".prefab";

    if (!File.Exists(destinationPath))
    {
        GameObjectUtility.SetStaticEditorFlags(modelAsset, StaticEditorFlags.LightmapStatic | StaticEditorFlags.NavigationStatic | StaticEditorFlags.BatchingStatic | StaticEditorFlags.OccludeeStatic | StaticEditorFlags.OccluderStatic | StaticEditorFlags.OffMeshLinkGeneration | StaticEditorFlags.ReflectionProbeStatic);

        foreach (Transform child in modelAsset.transform)
        {
            if (child.transform.name.Contains("UCX_"))
            {
                Renderer rend;
                rend = child.GetComponent<Renderer>();
                rend.enabled = !rend.enabled;

                string childname = child.transform.name;

                      GameObject childobject = modelAsset.transform.Find(childname).gameObject;
                      childobject.AddComponent<MeshCollider>();
            }
        }
        PrefabUtility.CreatePrefab(
            destinationPath,
            modelAsset);
    }
    else
    {
        PrefabUtility.ReplacePrefab(
            modelAsset,
            AssetDatabase.LoadAssetAtPath<GameObject>(destinationPath),
            ReplacePrefabOptions.ReplaceNameBased);
    }
}
private static void EnsureDirectoryExists(string directory)
{
    if (!Directory.Exists(directory))
        Directory.CreateDirectory(directory);
}
}
```

Comment: have you tried modifying an instance of your prefab and later replace your prefab with it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know what are you trying to achieve, but first of all, try to check `Generate Colliders` checkbox in model import (https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/FBXImporter-Model.html) maybe it will solve all your problems.

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nsKk2.png)

Second suggestion - update unity (no, your script will not work but having new version is always better way)

And according, to your initial request. All I can suggest is (code for unity 2018.3):

```
var go = GameObject.Instantiate(modelAsset);

GameObjectUtility.SetStaticEditorFlags(modelAsset, (StaticEditorFlags)(-1));

foreach (Transform child in go.transform)
{
    if (child.name.Contains("UCX_"))
    {
        Renderer rend;
        rend = child.GetComponent<Renderer>();
        rend.enabled = !rend.enabled;

        child.gameObject.AddComponent<MeshCollider>();
    }
}

PrefabUtility.SaveAsPrefabAsset(go, destinationPath);
GameObject.DestroyImmediate(go);
```

I slightly modified your script. Now mesh will be instantiated first, and prefab will be created from the instantiated object, not from asset.

The reason why error appears is: you are trying to modify `fbx` file, like it is a scene object. You should instantiate it first, then do changes whatever you want, and after that save it as prefab.

Comment: Thank you! It helped. Everything works now. I saved current version of the script to gist. [link] (https://gist.github.com/ACap99/61e309688a53377b0dceaa7efce1a8e3)